# Error message: Database Query failed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For some reason, the following code inside the query works in my MySQL command console, yet when I try to run it as a Query in PHP, something keeps going wrong and I'm not sure what. Here is the code I've done so far.

```
    //2. Perform database query 

    $query = "SELECT skills.element_id, content_model_reference.element_id, element_name FROM skills, content_model_reference WHERE (skills.element_id = content_model_reference.element_id)";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    //Tests if there was a query error
    if(!$result){
    die("Database query failed.");
    }
```

Is there something preventing the code that worked in MySQL (The line with SELECT) from working, or is my syntax somehow wrong?

EDIT: So it's saying I didn't select a database. Yet I thought I had. Here is the code above it:

```
//1. Create a database connection

$dbhost = "host"; //Host: Can be either an IP address, or a domain (like google.com).
$dbuser = "user";//User: The user that is connecting to the database.
$dbpass = "pass";//Password: This is the password that the user is using.
$dbname = "db";//Name: This is the name of the database.
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);//The value, 'handle,' is the connection.

//Test if connection occurred. Die ends the program/php, and in this case, also prints a message
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die("Database connection failed: ".
    mysqli_connect_error().
    " (". mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );

    }
```

Like I said, the error message I am getting is pertaining only to the query, the server is fine with my database connection.

Comment: You need to use mysql_error() to see what the actual error message is.

Comment: Don't use mysql_* anymore.  Use mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: It's saying that I didn't select a database, yet I thought I did.

Comment: So you've got to show us your code above this part.

Comment: 1.) Your using mysqli_* for the connection, but your using mysql_* for the QUERY... don't think you can do that, has to be one or the other (MYSQLI_ preffered)   Also the query should be: $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

Comment: @Mr.Bear you welcome, i added it as an ANSWER instead of a comment. Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

You're using mysqli_* for the connection, but you're using mysql_* for the QUERY... don't think you can do that, has to be one or the other (MYSQLI_ preffered). Also the query should be:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```